# Run a function a few seconds before video ends using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, video

I have a video the being played. How can I call a function 5 seconds before the end of the video?

I thought to put a timer when I start the video, the problem is that the user can control the video, and stop it and play again how many times he wants, so the timer is getting ineffective.

Examples would be very nice!

-----EDIT-----
this is an example to a code i'm using:

```
video = document.createElement("video");
    video.setAttribute("id", id);
    video.src = url;
    video.onended = function(e) {
        var playlistName = getPlaylistName();
        findNextSongToPlay(playlistName, playNextSong);
    };
```

I want the "onended" event to be called not in the end, but 5 seconds before..
So I need to change it a little bit..

Again, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which video player are you using? JW, browser built-in, etc?

Comment: Can you display the source code you have for the video player please? `I have a video the being played` Doesn't specify if the player is your own, a plug-in or a youtube video... Please give more information about this "video player"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a demo for you

> **Edit:** Updated Demo.

```js
window.onload=function(){
video = document.createElement("video");
    video.setAttribute("id", "Myvideo");
    video.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
    video.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"; 
    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", myfunc,false);
    document.body.appendChild(video);  
}

function myfunc(){
 if(this.currentTime > this.duration-5){
  //Less than 5 seconds to go. Do something here.

//---- For Demo display purposes
document.getElementById('Example').innerHTML="Less than 5 seconds to go!";
//---------
 } //End Of If condition.
//---- For Demo display purposes
else{document.getElementById('Example').innerHTML="";}
//---------
}
```

```html
<div id="Example"></div>
```

Since your player is dynamically created you can use:

```
video = document.createElement("video");
video.setAttribute("id", id);
video.src = url;
  //Add the event Listener
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", myfunc,false);
  video.onended = function(e) {
    var playlistName = getPlaylistName();
    findNextSongToPlay(playlistName, playNextSong);
  };
```

and that should call this function

```
function myfunc(){
    if(this.currentTime > this.duration-5){
        //Do something here..
    }
}
```

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: thanks a lot! a very helpful answer! I wish I could upvote to you... I promise when I can, I'll come back to this question and do it! tnx!!

Comment: You are very welcome. I have updated the first demo to fit your existing source code to show as a better example. Happy to help! :D Happy coding!

Comment: Good and short solution

Answer (score 0):

Sample with HTML5 player.

At most 100 milliseconds of difference can occur, not exactly 5 seconds.
But you can tune the script.

You can paste this code here to try it:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all

```
<html>
<body>
    <video id="vid" width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <script>
        var callOnce = true;

        function monitorVideo() {
            if ((vid.duration - vid.currentTime) < 5)
                if (callOnce) {
                    myFunction();
                    callOnce = false;
                }
        }

        function myFunction() {
            console.log('5 seconds');
        }

        setInterval(monitorVideo, 100);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not attach an event listener to the player rather than setting an interval? Listen for the `playing` event to trigger the if condition?

Comment: I think OP hasn't provided enough info to post anything more than a basic example.

Comment: I edited my answer.. Is this helpful? @Shikkediel - can you write an example for what you mean?

Comment: I actually already did but thought this post was going in a good direction (same as I initially had in mind) so I deleted it. I'll have a look at the new info though... think he's left the building for now, looks unfinished.

Comment: @FairPlay can you mark one answer as solving your problem? Please don't forget it. I think my answer is pretty straightforward and helps on the resolution of your edited question, with some modifications, of course.

Comment: Hey, already marked a question as solved, but promise when I get enough reputation to upvote, I'll go back to this question and upvote for you! Thx a lot for the help :)!

Answer (score -4):

Tell us what video player you are using.

If it is custom put an id on part that says how far in to the video you are and say

```
if (document.getElementById("bla").innerhtml === whatever 5 seconds before the end of the video is)
function();
```

---

Comment: I can't see this being very helpful.

Comment: It's not related to the question at all!